# ASP.NET MVC 4 AJAX.BeginForm and PartialViews

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am considering building a SPA using AJAX.BeginForm, however I am facing an issue when a user has JavaScript disabled, instead of redirecting him to _Layout.cshtml + PartialView.cshtml, it redirects him to just the PartialView.cshtml..

Is there a way to include the Layout and the PartialView in it (where it would be if JavaScript was enabled)?

Thanks

Edit:

Awesome.. Thanks.. I managed to get it working but I am not sure it's the best implementation..

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Newsletter newsletter)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Newsletters.Add(newsletter);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ViewData["message"] = "thanks for signing up to our newsletter!";
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return PartialView( "SimpleMessage" );
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And SimpleMessage.phtml is simply just @ViewData["message"];

whereas my View.phtml I have got a condition and checks whether ViewBag["message"] is set or not. If it's set, then it means it's a postback and doesn't show the form and shows the message instead, or else it shows the form:

Answer (score 5):

You can check if Action was called via Ajax, or not, and return different type of result

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        // Html fragment
        return PartialView();
    }
    else {
        // Complete HTML page
        return View();
    }
}
```

If it's postback, you can pass your model, or simple types (int, string) around as well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(Model model)
{
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        // Html fragment
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    else {
        // Complete HTML page
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** In your *specific case* I would do like this, but it's only my preference.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Newsletter newsletter)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Newsletters.Add(newsletter);
        db.SaveChanges();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("SimpleMessage");
        else
            return View("SimpleMessage")
    }
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView(newsletter);
    else
        return View(newsletter);
}
```

Comment: How will this function be called if there is no javascript ?

Comment: Ajax.BeginForm helper automatically takes care of that. It falls back to normal postback if javascript is disabled. Similar happens for Ajax.ActionLink helper, falls back to normal link behavior.

Comment: How would this work for form submissions where you return a PartialView with the success result?

Would I have to create a whole new View for a successfull result of that form and return that on success if JS is disabled?

Comment: That depends on your use-case. If your full view = (partial+layout) as you described, then you can return same ("MyAction.cshtml") view in both cases.

Comment: So let's say, if JavaScript => return PartialView..

If JavaScript is disabled, pass to the original View some ViewData.. If ViewData exists (in original View) then display success/fail message

Comment: Just give it a try - and it will become clear. In both cases return cshtml that represents full view (with layout property set). Partial result will simply ignore layout property and return only page body. ViewResult will return page with layout.

Comment: I've edited my post above including my solution, although not too sure if this is the best approach.